# How to show Product Schema/Structure data on Google?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, seo, schema

My website is in Javascript and i have implemented product schema on product details page.

Here is the code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"Product","url":"https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/65590697","name":"Size L, 5 mil, Industrial Grade, Powder Free Nitrile Disposable Gloves","image":["https://cdn.mscdirect.com/global/images/ProductImages/6559069-24.jpg"],"description":"Find Size L, 5 mil, Industrial Grade, Powder Free Nitrile Disposable Gloves - 9-1/2\" Long, Black, Textured, FDA Approved, Ambidextrous at MSC Industrial Supply, serving the metalworking, safety, and MRO industries for over 75 years","sku":"65590697","mpn":"GL6B-5MPFL","brand":{"@type":"Brand","name":"PRO-SAFE"},"aggregateRating":{"@type":"AggregateRating","ratingValue":5,"reviewCount":8},"offers":{"@type":"Offer","url":"https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/65590697","price":"17.79","priceCurrency":"USD","availability":"https://schema.org/Backorder"},"breadcrumb":{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":6,"item":{"name":"Disposable/Single Use Gloves","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/Safety/Personal-Protective-Equipment/Gloves-Hand-Protection/Gloves/Disposable-Single-Use-Gloves?navid=2106788"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":5,"item":{"name":"Gloves","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/Safety/Personal-Protective-Equipment/Gloves-Hand-Protection/Gloves?navid=2106719"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"name":"Gloves & Hand Protection","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/Safety/Personal-Protective-Equipment/Gloves-Hand-Protection?navid=2106592"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"name":"Personal Protective Equipment","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/Safety/Personal-Protective-Equipment?navid=2106404"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"name":"Safety","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/Safety?navid=2106309"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"name":"Home","@id":"https://www.mscdirect.com/ProductsHomeView"}}]}}</script>
```

The above code has product and breadcrumb schema both.

In Google, breadcrumb schema is showing, review schema is showing but product schema is not showing.

Anyone has solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check how the **[HTML validator sees the source code](https://validator.nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscdirect.com%2Fproduct%2Fdetails%2F65590697)** of the URL that is specified in the @id of your SD markup:

[image]

Check how the tester of Schema sees **[your structured data](https://validator.schema.org/?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscdirect.com%2Fproduct%2Fdetails%2F65590697)** for the URL specified in the @ id of your SD markup:

[image]

**[Rich results](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results/result/r%2Fbreadcrumbs?id=faeM4V3dIhuX1ciQZ7Da3w)** missing @id content of your SD markup.

Probably the source code of your page has some problems that interfere with the correct parsing of Googlebot.

Comment: Hi,Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool to create a product schema
[schema-markup-generator](https://technicalseo.com/tools/schema-markup-generator/)
And select "products" from the drop-down list and fill in the blank fields and get the output code